# How to enable column sorting on foreign fields in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

The following are my models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_one = models.CharField()
    a_two = model.ForeignKey(B)

class B(models.Model):
    b_one = models.Charfield()
    b_two = models.ForeignKey(C)

class C(models.Model):
    c_one = models.CharField()
    c_two = models.CharField()
```

I would like to create a table in django admin for model A with columns `a_one`, `a_two`, `b_one`, `c_one`, and `c_two` where all of them are sortable. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django enables column sorting on every field which defines the `admin_order_field` property, related fields don't define it but you can implement it by yourself creating a method which returns the related field and setting the `admin_order_field` property on it.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```py
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('a_one', 'b_one', 'c_one', 'c_two')

    def b_one(self, obj):
        return obj.a_two.b_one

    b_one.admin_order_field = 'a_two__b_one'

    def c_one(self, obj):
        return obj.a_two.b_two.c_one

    c_one.admin_order_field = 'a_two__b_two__c_one'

    def c_two(self, obj):
        return obj.a_two.b_two.c_two

    c_two.admin_order_field = 'a_two__b_two__c_two'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.